#  iis7.0 cant open asp.net4.0 sites

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, isapi

I have an asp 4.0 site on IIS7.0 that will not load. Error message:  **HTTP Error 404.17 - Not Found.**

ISAPI Filters for 4.0 do not exist in IIS.

**aspnet_regiis.exe** doesn't exist in :

**C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319**. So I cant install it.

**aspnet_filter.dll** does not exist in above folder either.

How should I fix this problem?

Thanks

Comment: If aspnet_regiis.exe isn't in the Framework version directory for v4.0 then your .NET Framework is missing stuff. Who knows what else doesn't work?

Comment: How is this a programming question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're missing stuff in your .NET install, I would open Programs and Features and do a context-menu->Repair on your .Net 4 items.

If you have no such items there, check your Features. If they're not available there either, go download a fresh install from the web.